# Renamed Ruby on Rails app on heroku and now it doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I launched my app, populated the database and have visited it several times with no issues.  But I just changed the name of the app by logging into my heroku account and visiting the app settings.  Now my app is malfunctioning.

Afterward I read the guide to how to change the name of the app and the end result is the same.  I literally just changed the name and now it doesn't work.  Can someone help me figure this out.  I also deleted the remote aliases that points to heroku and replaced them with the correct address.

Thanks for the help

**Heroku Logs**  (I'll try and clean it up some more)

```
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.659316+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Redirected to http://costrecovery-post.herokuapp.com/
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.659316+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 302 Found in 4ms
    (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.750709+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 74.143.68.203 at 2013-04-1720:27:29 +0000
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.753863+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by IncidentsController#index as HTML
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.962842+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered incidents/index.html.erb within layouts/application (15.5ms)
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.963111+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 207ms
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.966640+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.966640+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist at character 24
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.966640+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1):
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.966640+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     26:   <td><%= incident.location %></td>
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.966640+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     27:   <td><b><%= incident.status %></b> <% if current_user.admin == "yes" %><%= link_to "change", changestatus_incident_path(incident) %><% end %></td>
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.966640+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     28:   <% if current_us
er.admin == "yes" %>
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.966640+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     29:   <td><%=     User.find(incident.user_id).profile.name %> (<%= User.find(incident.user_id).profile.department %>)</td>
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.966640+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     30:   <% end %>
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.966640+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     31:     <td><%= link_t
o 'View Time Sheet', incident_timesheet_path(incident) %></td>
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.966640+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     32:   <td><%= link_to'Delete Incident', incident, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %><
/td>
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.966901+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/views/incidents/inde
x.html.erb:29:in `block in _app_views_incidents_index_html_erb___137155814596393
6561_33092660'
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.966901+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/views/incidents/inde
x.html.erb:22:in `each'
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.966901+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/views/incidents/inde
x.html.erb:22:in `_app_views_incidents_index_html_erb___1371558145963936561_3309
2660'
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.966901+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/controllers/incident
s_controller.rb:22:in `index'
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.966901+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
    ←[36m2013-04-17T20:27:29.966901+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
    ←[33m2013-04-17T20:27:29.977182+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/ host=costrecovery-post.herokuapp.com fwd="74.143.68.203" dyno=web.1 connect=
5ms service=246ms status=500 bytes=643
```

Comment: Can you please run `heroku logs` and post the result?

Comment: Define "doesn't work."

Comment: It automatically defaults to the 500.html page.

Comment: That error is typical of not running `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: can you look at `heroku pg:psql` and do a `\dt` in their to see if the tables exist.

Comment: I don't know what the issue was but when I checked it out this morning, everything was working fine.  Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this from the command line:

```
$ heroku apps:rename newname
-> http://newname.heroku.com/ | git@heroku.com:newname.git
-> Git remote heroku updated
```